# How to read xml file and How do I append a node inside XML tag file in java

Tags: java, xml

I am new to java, i am struggling in one program i don't know how to write it

I need some code that will read in the tasks and apply the appropriate task findings markup into the val.xml file.

For example:

A task in val.xml:

```
<task name="12-19" additionalIntervalInformationNeeded="No">
                         Converter (Cleaning)
  </task>
```

The matching task-findings markup in the findings.xml:

```
<tf taskid="olive-12-19">
<task-findings val="28">
<task-finding>
<title>Left Converter</title>
</task-finding>
</task-findings>
</tf>
```

So the goal is to use the tasked attribute value from the  element to locate the correct task-findings markup.

Incorporate the  element and all child elements into the task markup (just inside the ending  tag.

The result to the above examples would be as such:

```
<task name="12-19" additionalIntervalInformationNeeded="No">
                     Converter (Cleaning)
         <tf taskid="olive-12-19">
         <task-findings val="28">
         <task-finding>
         <title>Left Converter</title>
         </task-finding>
         </task-findings>
         </tf>
 </task>
```

Please suggest me how to write code.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+xml+api

Answer (score 0):

From your use case, it appears that you can write a program to read in the two xml files and then edit and write them as an output file. XML files can be read and written just like TXT files in Java, you'll just need to change the file extension while reading and saving the files. This will need you to write your own parser or use regex etc methods.

Another way to go is by writing a [JAXP or the Java API for XML](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/intro-140052.html), provided by Oracle. This will help you read, process and edit XML files via Java.

There are other parser APIs called [DOM Parser API](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parser.htm) & [SAX (Simple API for XML) API](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_sax_parser.htm). That can be used to read and alter XML files. This was used by older Java versions and are useful for small XML files. Currently, the StaX or Streaming API for XML is used instead.

The tutorial blog [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html) will help you get an idea of StaX library parsing XML files via Java.